# .net unique values from two dimension array

Tags: c#, .net

I define array as

```
var arr = new double[image.Width, image.Height];
```

I need select unique values from this array

how i can do it?

Comment: Take a look at LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb397926.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Find Value in Multidimensional Array and return all items c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612456/find-value-in-multidimensional-array-and-return-all-items-c-sharp)

Comment: Not possible. Unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to flatten the multi dimensional array and then do a distinct on the result:

```
var flattened = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(0)).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(1)).Select(y => arr[x, y]));

var distinct = flattened.Distinct().ToList();
```